# Is there a way to make a simple API request in DocuSign? The tutorials seem like they are only designed for full blown apps

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, request, docusignapi

In the past (outside of DocuSign) I would look at the API calls on manual actions, play with postman, then repeat the API calls in a simple program... but DocuSign seems like it's looking only looking for full blown hosted applications. Is this something I am not understanding about OAuth 2.0 ?

Not trying to make some massive integration with DocuSign I'm just trying to make a one time set of calls to update a bunch of users

Tried following the DocuSign API tutorials but they seem designed for big hosted applications

Answer (score 0):

We have something that I think will be exactly what you want.
It's a JWT console app for Python, it has dozen files and it runs from your PC. All you need is one time consent and you can run your API calls.
Now, you asked to update some users, not sure what that means, what we show in this app is sending an envelope, which is the most common request, but you can tweak this app to do your user update. If you explain what you want to update - I can help further.

https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart/

Select "Python" and then select the "JWT" option and you'll get a small tool-like download for a console app (not a full web app).

Answer (score 0):

See the **live** API demos that run in your browser!

[DocuSign CodePen examples](https://codepen.io/collection/RzQPKB)

```
SlackOverflow requires
Some code here if I provide
A link to CodePen.
Hopefully this is enough
```